# Want to show my logo in the left side of the screen in the navbar, and the other elements at the right

Tags: html, css

i am working in a webapp, i would like to show my navbar with the logo in the left and the other elements(links) in the right side, but when using some approaches i searched in the web everything seems to get ruined, so i would like to know what i am doing wrong and which is the correct way of solving that problem.

```css
/*Body CSS*/
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color:black;
    font-family: 'GlacialIndifferenceRegular';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/*Video CSS*/
.bg-video-div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}

.bg-video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

/*Navbar CSS*/
nav{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

nav ul{
    text-align: right;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

nav ul li a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 25px;
    transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #34495e;
}

nav ul li img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

#logo{
    height:25%;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
{%load staticfiles%}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>MediTracker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org/face/glacial-indifference" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'home/css/home.css'%}">
    <link rel="shortcut-icon" type="image/ico" href="{%static 'home/favicon/favicon.ico'%}"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bg-video-div">
        <video loop muted autoplay class="bg-video">
            <source src="{%static 'home/videos/background.mp4'%}" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li id="image"><img id="logo" align="middle" src="{%static 'home/logo/logo.png'%}" alt=""></li>
            <li><a href="{%url 'login'%}">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="{%url 'register'%}">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logo has a `width` of `25%`
Your nav has a `width` of `100%`
this **(total 125%)** doesn't fit inside of a `frame`, whiches size would be `100%`
Try not setting the `width` of the `nav`.
If it displays as `block` (css `display:block`), it will automatically take the whole available horizontal space.
If this doesn't work, try setting the `width` to `75%`.

Comment: It worked, but now my image appears huge, which is the best approach to set the image size so that is fits exactly in the navbar without losing resolution?:(

Comment: @LuisRodriguez Just set the height/width to a lower amount (like 40px)